# Basis of the Dual Space of Polynomial Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

I have the following problem:

Let $V=\mathcal{P}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$. Define $\alpha_k : V\to\mathbb{R}$ by

$$
\alpha_k(p)=\int_{-1}^{1}t^kp(t)dt,\qquad p\in V.
$$

Show that $\{\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ is a basis for the dual space $V^*$ of $V$.

Here is my proof attempt:

---

We just need to show linear independence as $\operatorname{dim}(V^*)=\operatorname{dim}(V)=n+1$, and linearly independent sets of the right length form a basis.

We proceed by induction on $n$. The base case is trivial since when $n=0$ we have a set of only one vector and is thus linearly independent.

For the inductive step, suppose the result holds for $i=0,\dots,n-1$, i.e., the set $\{\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_{n-1}\}$ is linearly independent. Thus whenever $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{n-1}$ satisfy

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_k\alpha_k=0,\qquad\forall p\in\mathcal{P}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R})
$$

we have $c_0=c_1=\cdots=c_{n-1}$. Let $c_0,\dots,c_n$ satisfy

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_k\alpha_k=0,\qquad\forall p\in\mathcal{P}_n(\mathbb{R}).
$$

Suppose $n$ is even. The case where $n$ is odd is similar, and is omitted.

Let $p(t)=t$. Then we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    0=\sum_{k=0}^nc_k\alpha_k(t) &= \sum_{k=0}^{n- 
    1}c_k\int_{-1}^{1}t^{k+1}dt+c_n\int_{-1}^{1}t^{n+1}dt \\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_k\int_{-1}^{1}t^{k+1}dt \\
    &\implies c_0=c_2=\cdots=c_{n-2}=0.\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Now let $p(t)=1$. Then 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    0 &= c_1\int_{-1}^{1}tdt+c_3\int_{-1}^{1}t^3dt+\cdots +c_{n- 
    1}\int_{-1}^{1}t^{n-1}dt+c_n\int_{-1}^{1}t^ndt \\
    &= c_n\int_{-1}^{1}t^ndt \\
    &\implies c_n=0.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Finally, with $p(t)=t^3$, we have

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
c_1\int_{-1}^{1}t^4dt+c_3\int_{-1}^{1}t^6dt+\cdots +c_{n-1}\int_{-1}^{1}t^{n+2}dt &= 0 \\
\implies c_1=c_3=\cdots=c_{n-1} &= 0. \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Hence the set $\{\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ is linearly independent. $\Box$

---

Does this work? Is there anywhere I left out too much detail or anything that needs to be modified? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you set $p(t)=t$ you ended up with a weighted sum of the $c_k$ equalling zero.  You cannot conclude from that that $c_k=0$ for $k$ even.

Comment: Try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthogonality

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand why not. For each $p(t)$ it is true that $\sum_{k}c_k\alpha_k(p(t))=0$ from what I said, so I should be able to pick any polynomial, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another proof of linear independence is this:

Let $\lambda_0,...,\lambda_n$ be s.t. $\sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i\alpha_i=0$. Hence, for all $p \in V$,
$$
\int_{-1}^1q(t)p(t)dt=0
$$

where $q(t)=\sum_{i=0}^n\lambda_it^i$. As $q\in V$, we deduce
$$
\int_{-1}^1q^2(t)dt=0
$$

hence $q(t)=0$ for all $t\in [-1,1]$. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, if $q$ were not the zero polinomial, it has only $n+1$ complex roots. But, since all $t \in [-1,1]$ are roots of $q$, $q$ is the zero polinomial. Hence, $\lambda_i=0$ for all $i\in \{0,...,n\}$

Comment: Couldn't it be true that $q(t)=0$ on $[-1,1]\setminus A$ where $A$ is a subset of $[-1,1]$ of measure zero? I mean I see how the result would still follow but I feel to be rigorous we'd have to appeal to measure theory concepts. Or is that not right?

Comment: Not exactly. As $q$ is a polynomial, it's a continuous function. By continuity, if $t_0\in [-1,1]$ s.t. $q(t_0)\ne 0$, there is a subinterval $I\subset [-1,1]$, including $t_0$, where $q^2(t)>\epsilon>0$. Hence $\int_{-1}^1 q^2(t)dt > \epsilon m(I)>0$. Hence, $q$ must equal zero over $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Oh true. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The proof is incorrect. You can calculate (easily) that

$$ \alpha_k(t^l) = \begin{cases} \frac{2}{n + l + 1} & \text{if $n + l$ is even} \\ 0 & \text{if $n + l$ is odd} \end{cases}$$

Your argument then goes: take an arbitrary linear combination $c_0 \alpha_0 + \cdots + c_n \alpha_n = 0$ and feed $t$ into it:
$$ (c_0 \alpha_0 + \cdots + c_n \alpha_n)(t) = c_0 \alpha_0(t) + \cdots + c_n \alpha_n(t) = \frac{c_1}{2} + \frac{c_3}{4} + \cdots = 0$$
but you cannot conclude from this that $c_1 = 0$, $c_3 = 0$, etc.

Comment: Okay, I can see that is an issue. Do you have any suggestions on what I could do?

Answer (score 2):

Big Hint:  The Legendre Polynomials $\{P_0(t), P_1(t), \ldots, P_n(t)\}$ form a basis for $\mathbb P_n(\mathbb R)$, the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$.  Form the matrix $A_{ij}=\alpha_i(P_j(t))$.  Use the orthogonality of the Legendre Polynomials to show that $A$ is non-singular.  Now if $\sum_k^{n+1} c_k \alpha_k=0$, then for $i=0,1, \ldots, n+1$,
$$
0 = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} c_k \alpha_k(P_i(t))= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} c_k A_{ki}.
$$

Can you now show that $c=(c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_n)$ must be the zero vector?

If you can prove that $\sum_k^{n+1} c_k \alpha_k=0$ implies that $c$ is the zero vector, you have proven that the $\{\alpha_k\}$ must be independent.